# Newline in block name

Tags: makecode

[image]

The minecraft make code example has multiline blocks.

How do I also make my blocks this tall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used

```
//% inlineInputMode=external
```

This breaks blocks (newlines) where each input is. Doesn't give you control over where the line breaks go.